# How to load from relative path in WPF application?

Tags: c#, windows, path

I'm reading an xml file and want to make it from a relative directory based on the location of the application, similar to ASP.NET with Server.MapPath or using the tilda.

How can you get the relative path in WPF?

```
WORKS: XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\testdata\customers.xml");
DOES NOT WORK: XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"~\Data\customers.xml");
DOES NOT WORK: XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"~/Data/customers.xml");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Data\customers.xml");
```

OR

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@".\Data\customers.xml");
```

BTW, this has nothing to do with WPF and everything to do with Windows paths.

Comment: hmmm, neither of those seems to work, I have the customers.xml set on "Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always", any other suggestions?

Comment: I suggest Environment.CurrentDirectory is what you expect, and actually ensuring that the Customers.xml file is where you expect in the output.

Comment: string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: urm... why is this the accepted answer if it 'doesnt seem to work'
this answer concerns me cos if the current directory changes it won't work

Answer (score 17):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(
    Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
        @"Data\customers.xml"));
```

I assume the `Data` directory is going to get deployed with your app, in the same root directory as your EXE. This is generally safe, except where shadow copying is involved; for example, when you use NUnit to test this code. (With shadow copying, the assemblies that make up your app get copied to a temporary directory, but files like this get left behind.)

Assuming you're not planning to modify `customers.xml` after deployment, the safest way to handle this is to embed the file as a resource within your assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Try `File.Create("./HiImHere.txt")` to see where is the point directory; after that try the path relative to where `HiImHere.txt` is.